# Is it possible to set the column default to LOCALTIMESTAMP using Liquibase and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'd like to have a column on a table of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE but have it default to the time the row was inserted. We use Liquibase so I'd like to accomplish this using the standard Liquibase syntax.

I would expect that would look like:

```
<changeSet author="chuck" id="2012-07-24.1">
    <addColumn tableName="foo">
        <column name="createdOn" type="timestamp" defaultValue="LOCALTIMESTAMP">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

This generates the SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD "createdOn" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'LOCALTIMESTAMP';
```

I can modify this statement and remove the single quotes around LOCALTIMESTAMP and it will execute in psql.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD "createdOn" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP;
```

Has anyone else encountered this with Liquibase and PostgreSQL? I could rewrite this as a  statement as a workaround but wanted to try and do this the Liquibase way.

Comment: Wild guesses (no expert with Liquibase): can you remove the double-quotes here? `defaultValue=LOCALTIMESTAMP` Or, if that's not possible, would Liquibase understand `defaultValue="now()::timestamp"`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: double quotes can't be removed as this is XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [defaultValueComputed](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/column) for function calls. `defaultValue` assumes a string value.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter had the right idea for the proper Postgres default setting this answer has the correct Liquibase attribute. It ends up looking like:
<column name="createdOn" type="timestamp" defaultValueComputed="now()::timestamp">

Comment: @cclark: [LOCALTIMESTAMP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is a function, too. For historical reasons and standard compliance it does not have parenthesis attached like other functions. With `defaultValueComputed` it probably works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, defaultValueComputed works.

```
<column name="actiondate" type="timestamp with time zone" defaultValueComputed="current_timestamp"/>
```